# How I can filter a Collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the follow code

```
$tecnico = Tecnico::with('servicios')->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
        if($tecnico != ''){
            $servicios = $tecnico->servicios;
            $servicio = $servicios->where('idServicio', $id);
        }
```

The `Servicio`have many `Tecnico` and  `Tecnico` have many `Service`

In this case I only need a `Tecnico` from a `Auth_token` later also need all `Servicio` from that `Tecnico` but filter by `id` When I run the above code the following error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()
```

in `$servicio = $servicios->where('idServicio', $id);`

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$tecnico = Tecnico::with(array('servicios' => function($q) use ($id) {
    $q->where('idServicio', $id);
}))->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
```

So, you'll get the `Tecnico` model whose related `Servicio->id` is equal to `$id`, then you may use `$tecnico->servicios->first()` to get the first `Servicio` and if there are more than one `Servicio` (Most probably won't) in the collection then you may use a `foreach` loop (Basically in the `view`). You may check more about [this aka Eager Load Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) on the `Laravel` website.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is either:

```
// if idServicio is set as primary key on Servicio model
$servicio = $tecnico->servicios->find($id); 


// in case idServicio was just a property and not necessarily unique do this:
// it return Collection of Servicio models matching $id
$servicio = $recnico->servicios->filter(function ($servicio) use ($id) {
   return $servicio->idServicio == $id;
});
```

Anyway if you really need only that particular `Servicio`, use eager loading constraints like @WhereWolf suggested rather than filtering the collection.